# Prove equivalent metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X_1=[1,2]$ and $X_2=[0,1]$. Let $d_1$ denote Euclidean and let $d_2(x,y)=2|x-y|$ in $X_2$. Show that $(X_1,d_1)$ and $(X_2,d_2)$ are equivalent metric spaces.

How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you share your thoughts? It helps to format using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Comment: Can different metrics on different sets be equivalent? All of the definitions of equivalence I know treat two different metrics on the same set.

Comment: this is a book example, so I guess it should be possible - I know there should be a function f, such that d1(x,y)=d2(f(x),f(y)), which seems in this case to be f(x) = x-1, because the boundary of the second set are exactly smaller for 1.